# Google maps markers aren't showing up

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I seem to have searched every SO question and the google maps api but can't see why my markers aren't showing up on my map. I've taken the code almost exactly from other areas and the console isn't showing any errors. This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
        //declare namespace
        var up206b = {};

        //declare map
        var map;

//set the geocoder
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        function trace(message) 
        {
            if (typeof console != 'undefined') 
            {
                console.log(message);
            }
        }

        //Function that gets run when the document loads
        up206b.initialize = function()
        {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.954465, 115.859586);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                // Buggles marker location

            var locations = [
              ['Test 1', -31.9522, 115.8589],
              ['Test 2', -31.1522, 115.4589],
              ['Test 3', -31.9322, 115.1589],
              ['Test 4', -31.5522, 115.9589],
              ['Test 5', -32.9522, 115.2589]
            ];

              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

              var marker, i;

              for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                      map: map
                  });

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                      return function () {
                          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                          infowindow.open(map, marker);
                      }
                  })(marker, i));
              }

        }


        //geocode function
        up206b.geocode = function() 
        {
            var address = $('#location').val();
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map, 
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                        $('#buggles-locations').removeClass('hidden');

                } 
                else 
                {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        }


    </script>
```

and the example I followed included this in the body to load the function

```
<body onload="up206b.initialize()">
```

The example is here http://buggles.crushme.com.au/index.php Does anyone have any ideas why this might not be working?

Thanks

Comment: I've also tried just adding one marker using a really basic method and that still wouldn't show so I'm assuming I've done something wrong on a very basic level but I'm not very good at javascript so can't see what.

Comment: And where is the map in your shared link?

Comment: Sorry, it's under the main image slider, it slides in when you enter an address to search but for development I've just taken that off for ease of debugging. I've completely changed my code and got the markers but not the geocoding so just trying to combine them.

Comment: So, what is your problem? Markers not showing up or something else? Because with your code I got all markers... And if I write something in search box at your page error is reported: `Uncaught ReferenceError: up206b is not defined `

Comment: Sorry, I think I might not have a problem any more. After trying enough code variations, I've got the markers and now the geocoding works too. Now I just need to try and understand why my latest code works and the others didn't! Sorry for time wasting.

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                  return function () {
                      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                      infowindow.open(map, marker);
                  }
              })(marker, i));
```

value of i = max length of locations, you can save i to label of marker

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : myLatLng,
        map : map,
        title: i.toString(),            
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      infowindow.setContent(partInt(locations[this.getTitle())][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```